# How to transform numbers with decimal point in numbers smaller tham 1000

Tags: geometry, functions

How to transform numbers with decimal point in numbers smaller then 1000. For example what i did in this case: 
for 1.09649 i multiply by 10000, i subtract 10000 and once again i subtract 900. (1.09649 * 10000 - 10000 - 900). But if is 2.49649 i need to find another solution. Is there a way to do it with some of the Math functions? I need only the value that changes between 2 or more same numbers like 1.09649, 1.09730, 1.09689.

Comment: What is the purpose of the transformation?

Comment: The numbers, will draw a fine line in a Chart.

Comment: Um.... what are you *doing*? $1.09649\times 10000-10000 - 900=64.9$ but why is this what you *want*.  What are you trying to achieve?  You can do $2.49649 \times 10000-10000 -900 = 14064.9$ but I assume that is irrelevant to want you are trying to do. But I don't know what you *are* trying to do.  You could do $2.49649\times 10000 - 20000-4000 =964.9$.  Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: Could you give a few pairs of inputs and outputs?  I can't guess what output you intended for the input $2.49649$?  (For $1.09649$, you seem to have gotten $98749$.)

Comment: @fleablood : $1.09649 \cdot 10000 - 900 = 108749$.

Comment: @EricTowers you didn't subtract 10000. $1.09649\times 10000= 10964.9$ and $10964.9 - 10000 = 964.9$ and $964.9-900 = 64.9$

Comment: @fleablood : <squints at screen>  How many zeroes?  Now I *want* commas in these numbers.  Why aren't there commas in these numbers?  The title promised commas...

Comment: To multiply by number length (100000, 8) and to simple divide until i obtain the preferred format?

Comment: Or with PI, cos, sin. Until 360. Converting in hundrets.

Comment: Yes here are some pairs: 1.09358* 10000 - 10000 - 900 = 35.79
1.09290* 10000 - 10000 - 900 = 29
1.09256* 10000 - 10000 - 900 = 25.6
1.09269* 10000 - 10000 - 900 = 26.9
1.09296* 10000 - 10000 - 900 = 29.59
1.09182* 10000 - 10000 - 900 = 18.20
1.09162* 10000 - 10000 - 900 = 16.20.

Comment: Well is seems like you've figured it out.  For those numbers multiplying by 10000 and then subtracting $10900$.  That works.  What is your actual question.

Comment: To do it with $2.49whatever$ we need some idea of what range of numbers you want and what range of output you want and .... you approximate.  But basically you multiply to get a good scale and then subtract to get a good offset.  The question is do you to guestimate to make the math easy.  Or do you want it perfect.

Comment: Yes, i figure it out only for one pair of numbers, i need a formula to suite all, and finding the interval between pairs is very good idea. Thank you for the answer. It sure is the correct answer for mapping the interval between two close together small scale numbers. I need to test it.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do these operations on a list of numbers? Are you trying to find an appropriate way to plot a graph of the numbers so that the relative differences between numbers are accurately shown, even if the percentage differences are very small? Because if you try to plot two numbers like $1.09730$ and $1.09740$ on a scale that starts at zero, nobody will be able to see that they are two different numbers, so you might want to "zoom in" so that only numbers between $1.09$ and $1.10$ are on the graph, or even just numbers between $1.097$ and $1.098.$

Comment: I think you should stop using the words "comma numbers." It is not standard mathematical English and is likely to fail to communicate what you mean. Try describing what you mean in standard terms. If you mean numbers between $0$ and $1,$ say "between $0$ and $1$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are try to do is map the interval between two close together small scale numbers $a,b$ to $c$ and $d$ were $c$ and $d$ are at a more reasonable scale and offset appropriately.

For example:

If you had you want to graph the three numbers $1.09649, 1.09730, 1.09689$ but on a line only about $2000$ pixels wide so that $1.096 \mapsto 0$ and $1.098 \mapsto 2000$ and $1.09649 \mapsto 649$ and $1.09730 \mapsto 730$ and $1.09689\mapsto 689$.

So to do this you need the smallest point on your input.  Call it $a$.  (In this case $a = 1.09649$)  And the largest point in you input.  Call it $b$. (In this case $b = 1.09730$)  Then you need the smallest point in your output. Call it $c$. (In this case lets say $c=0$.) and you need the largest point of your output.  Call it $d$.  (In this case $d = 100$)

Create a scale ratio.  $R = \frac {d-c}{b-a}$.  (In this case $R = \frac {100 - 0}{1.0730- 1.09649} = \frac {100}{0.00081} \approx 123456$  [That's a *weird* coincidence!].  Then if you have any $x$ between $a$ and $b$ you map it to $x \mapsto (x-a)*R + c$.  In this case $x= 1.09689$ and $y = (1.09689- 1.09649)\cdot 123456 + 0 = (0.00040)\cdot 123456 = 49.3824\approx 49$.

Which intuitively should make sense as $1.09689$ is $\frac {40}{81}\approx 49\%$ of the way  between $1.09649$ and $1.09730$.

.....

Or not so labor intensive, not so stark, not such firm borders, and a little more intuitive and holistic...

If you want the numbers $1.09649, 1.09730, 1.09689$ to go from a little less than $1.09649$, say $1.09640$ to a little more than $1.09730$ so $1.09740$ so that's a difference of $0.00100$ it makes sense to make the scale $100$ and the offset $1.09640$.  So subtract $1.09640$ and multiply by a high enough power of $10$ to turn $0.001$ to $100$ (that's multiplying by $100,000$.)  To get the obvious $1.09649\mapsto 9$ and $1.09730\mapsto 90$ and $1.09689\mapsto 49$.

But that's $a = 1.09640$ and $b = 1.09740$ and $c=0$ and $d= 0$ and $R= \frac {100-0}{1.09740-1.09640} = 100,000$ and $x \mapsto (x-a)*R + c$ as above.

......

Or was your question about how to calculate powers of $10$?

Comment: Even if i find the difference between 1.09730 and 1.09740 is still a comma number. The result i will need to multiply it again with a high number to obtain a even higher number. After i do not know if is 2, 3, or 4 number long. This answer to formula '≈49' is the answer i need between 2 numbers. Because on the chart i need only the y axis to be found out and is between the first number and the following .Then i can multiply it exactly by 10 and so on. But the ratio is important.

Comment: Well, multiply it by as high a power of $10$ as you need.  What is the issue?  .... what do you mean by "comma number"?

Comment: Decimal point not comma number! Sorry about that. I try to get a good ratio out from the fractional part of this decimal numbers.

Comment: Well, .... where are you having trouble.  Just do it.  Find an appropriate scale and scale to that and subtract appropriately.  What range of numbers are you having trouble with?

Comment: I try with : a=1.32520, b=1.32523, c=1.32530, d=1.32527. Where a is the closest to the 0 on x axis of the chart. How to make a good ratio for every number so i can point it on a chart with maximum x=1000 and y=1000?

Comment: I have for example two numbers A=1.32520 and B=1.32523. How to make a good ration number from each decimal numbers so i can draw a chart line within 1000 x 1000, knowing x axis is 144.

Comment: Well the only significant difference at the last digit.  So multiply by $100000$ so ge $132520$ and $132523$.  Subtract $132520$ to get $0$ and $3$ and then multiple by, say $300$ to get $0$ and $900$.

Comment: It works perfectly fine.